# Cannot find class [com.seerlabs.sonic.api.components.DaoManager] for bean with name 'daoManager'

Tags: java, spring, git, spring-mvc

**The Problem:**

My friends and I have been working on a Spring project with multiple Git branches. As a rule of thumb, nobody touches a branch that isn't his. We can pull other's branch as a local branch, but we never push from it.

Most of it has been setup already and is up and running, `root-context.xml`, `servlet-context.xml`, etc.

Suddenly, this happens:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.seerlabs.sonic.api.components.DaoManager] for bean with name 'daoManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.seerlabs.sonic.api.components.DaoManager
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.seerlabs.sonic.api.components.DaoManager] for bean with name 'daoManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.seerlabs.sonic.api.components.DaoManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1786)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've never touched any of those files. `servlet-context.xml` is saying the class doesn't exist, but it's right there:

[image]

As a matter of fact, command+clicking (I'm on a Mac) that very line takes me the DaoManager class itself.

**What I tried:**

Only what I know. Since I never messed with that code, I'm assuming it has something to do with branch switching, or something. So I tried:

- Cleaning up the project, via -> Project -> Clean
- Closing and opening the project
- Pulling from the main repo
- Switching to other local branches

Of note is that after doing the latter, the error spread to the other local branches! Yikes!

And of course, doing the above to the branches does nothing either.

Any ideas? Anything else I can provide?

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with git? And if it does, please provide your git status. The error you have provided is not really helpful

Comment: @TheGeorgeous, the thing is, I'm not actually sure. It started after I switched between branches. Like I said, switching to different branches didn't fix it. `git status` for all the branches read nothing to commit, working directory clean. At this point, I'd like to see if erasing everything and pulling would make a difference.

Comment: Show DAOmanager.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by deleting everything and pulling from the remote. Not an elegant solution, but it was the only thing I could think off. Good thing my repo was up to date.